# Ubuntu snap-to-edge feature for XP

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-9.10

I am running Windows XP SP3 dual booting with Ubuntu 9.10.

I really like the snap to edge feature of Ubuntu and wondered if you could get that feature in XP. This would basically prevent any windows from straying from the workspace and would allow windows to snap to the edges of the screen and to the edges of other windows.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[allSnap](http://www.allsnap.org) might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For simple snap-to-edge functionality, [WindowSpace](http://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html) can do this. If you want it to resize to half the screen upon snapping like Windows 7 Aero Snap, check out [AeroSnap](http://www.aerosnap.de/index_eng.htm) which works on XP/Vista.

Comment: Hmmm WindowSpace looks good! But, it's not free. I know about AeroSnap, but it kept crashing on me, and doesn't have the same effect as WindowSpace. No other ideas?? haha

Comment: If you're content with a little programming, you could do this with Autohotkey: http://autohotkey.com . Just make a loop that constantly checks the location of the window. If it goes within one of the bounds by say, 50 pixels, move it to touch that bound.

Answer (score 0):

[Win Split Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/) might also be worth looking at, although it's more 'active' than 'passive' in that you have to use the keyboard shortcuts to throw the windows to the side of the screen (or the monitor).